# it is need a paid apple developer id for testing app in iphone from xcode.?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

my app running on simulator but when i run on iphone 8 by Xcode 8 it build fail and gives the code signing error.

so simply i want to know that for testing on real device it is necessary for apple membership.

Comment: And you really can't be bothered to do any searching or googling, or even look up this info on Apple's site?

Comment: You need a developer membership. It doesn't need to be paid

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to be have paid account if you just need to check app in your single device. if you want to upload it on app store then you need to be get apple membership account.

You can check this link for more details.
https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6

this is also one good blog on this.
https://blog.ionicframework.com/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

Another Option.
https://livecode.com/how-to-create-a-free-ios-development-provisioning-profile/